# Recognizing a telegram id channel exists or not in bot

Tags: bots, telegram

I want to send a channel id to my telegram bot and the bot recognize the channel exists or not,after that save it in database,is it possible?how handle it?

Comment: Please at least provide some code you started with.

Comment: the code is not written,because I don't know what to do after getting the id of channel

Comment: My comment was a nice way of saying that you don't come here asking for the whole solution of your problem. Start with something, put some effort, obtain some results and when your really blocked, come back with a concrete question. This is how this site works. And in such sense, the code *is* necessary.

Comment: `getChatMember` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

via ID a bot can get info of a channel only if it has been inside it.
Otherwise if public channels are enough and you don't need to check private ones, you can use usernames and it will works (You can use getChat method).

users API (mtproto) instead of bot api should allow more things about it